# Any way to set distributable element in tomcat conf rather than WEB-INF/web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

We will release our product as a WAR file and will deploy it into tomcat.

However there a few different projects using the same WAR file, but some will use  cluster and others not.

The `WEB-INF/web.xml` in WAR file does not have `<distributable/>` element.

So now every time we need to manually modify `WEB-INF/web.xml` to add the `<distributable/>` after deploying the WAR file to a cluster site.

My question is that is there any way to avoid this manual step to modify `WEB-INF/web.xml`?

Could we define it in tomcat config (so that it is one-shot setup and no need manual step every release)?

Or could we enable `<distributable/>` in programmatic way?

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When we are using Memcached or Redis as the tomcat session replication manager (refer to https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager), the `<distributable/>` element is not neccessary in `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Then we can always release WAR file without that element in web.xml.